# How XMLHttpRequest behaves in combination with same-origin policy

Tags: html, security, http, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

I've a basic HTML, hosted in www.foodomain.com, with a simple script that just tries to make a POST call to a site located to another domain (www.bardomain.com), in order to provoke an action to be performed on that site.  The attacker.html file is:

The hosting

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Attacker.html</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://www.bardomain.com/attacked.php";
    var params = "action=deleteAll";
    http.open("POST", url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert("fet");
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
</script>
</head>
<body>
     Some presentation text ...
</body>
</html>
```

As far as I know that behaviour should be blocked by the web browser due to its same-origin policy, but in fact the POST call to the www.bardomain.com site is done, though the action is never accomplished because the apache server sends an HTTP 302 message:

```
www.bardomain.com:80 192.168.56.1 - - [14/Dec/2014:12:57:30 +0100] "POST /attacked.php HTTP/1.1" 302 509 "http://www.foodomain/attacker.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
```

Since it's a HTTP 302 response the action is not really done, but I didn't even expect the request to be sent by the browser (since it's to another domain). I'd really appreciate if anybody could give me an explanation to this behaviour.

On the other hand, another curious behavior occurs if instead of accessing the attacker.html file from apache, I just load the file in the Eclipse web brower, the POST message is sent and returns an HTTP 200 message, so the action is performed in the www.bardomain.com:

```
www.bardomain.com:80 192.168.56.1 - - [14/Dec/2014:13:20:52 +0100] "POST /attacked.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1586 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.78.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/522.0"
```

Any explanation to those behaviours?

Answer (score 0):

Sending information is not blocked, but the other end may not send you back anything.  Also, your browser may not use scripts loaded from outside your host domain if the CORS headers are not found with the returning payload.

In other words, the whole Cross Site Request Security is a two way hand shake before it works.  The client (your browser) typically makes a request with the verb OPTIONS to verify it will be allowed to request the script in the first place.  The server (other end) then replies with the VERBS you can use to request stuff from outside its domain.

Then, when you actually request the asset, the client provides HOST information for the server to validate and if all is well, other headers will be added to the return telling the client that the information was requested and okay to use.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Thanks for the answer Phil. I understand the theory behind what you explained, but in the example I've posted an HTTP POST request is sent, but not an HTTP OPTIONS request. So the question now is, why isn't the browser sending an HTTP OPTIONS request, but an HTTP POST instead? And is the HTTP 302 response message the normal answer in this case? Or maybe there is something wrong in the code I wrote?

Comment: First of all, you are not making a cross site scripting request...you are just making a POST to an external endpoint.  That is not restricted.  As for why you are getting 302 when ran from the web and 200 from a local file as to do with how the endpoint is processing your request.